# Abstract algebra ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field and $K[x]$ be the ring of polynomials over $K$ in a single variable $x$ for a polynomial $f$ belong to $K[x]$. Let $(f)$ denote the ideal in $K[x]$ generated by $f$. show that $(f)$ is a maximal ideal in  $K[x]$ if and  only iff $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over $K$.

Comment: And what tools are you allowing yourself to use? Do you have Euclidean division, or do you want to prove that for yourself along the way?

Comment: In this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39644/proving-that-an-ideal-in-a-pid-is-maximal-if-and-only-if-it-is-generated-by-an-ir) you will find useful stuff.

Comment: For $"\rightarrow"$, let $f$ generate a maximal ideal of $K[X]$. Try a proof by contradiction by considering $f=pq$.

For $"\leftarrow"$, use the definition of maximal ideal.

Comment: @AlgebraicallyClosed next time you edit, consider to include more than one tag.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(f)$ maximal and suppose $f=gh$ for certain polynomial $g,h$. In particular, $(f)\subset (g)$ and by maximality of $(f)$, you get $(f)=(g)$, i.e. there is $k$ s.t. $kf=g$ and thus $$kgh=g\implies (kh-1)g=0\implies kh=1,$$
because $g\neq 0$, and thus $h$ is a unit. Therefore $f$ is irreducible.

Conversely, if $(f)$ is irreducible, then $K[X]/(f)$ is a field and thus $(f)$ is maximal.