# How does a polynomial not being in an Ideal imply that the polynomial and generator are relatively prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the following claim; that if I have some principle ideal of F[x] generated by some irreducible polynomial p(x), and I consider another polynomial a(x) which is not a member of the ideal, that p(x) and a(x) are relatively prime, i.e. the only common divisor of the two is a constant polynomial.

What I understand that if a(x) is not a member of the ideal generated by p(x), then a(x) is not of the form p(x)s(x) for any s(x) in F[x].  How does this idea continue to show that the GCD of a(x) ad p(x) is 1?

Comment: Let $\,d = \gcd(p,a).\,$ Since $\,d\mid p\,$ and $\,p\,$ is irred either $\,d = 1\,$ or $\,d = p.\,$ But $\,p = d = \gcd(p,a)\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a,\,$ contra hypothesis. Thus $\,d = 1.\ $ Note: we use "equal" vs. "associate" above since wlog we may assume that $p$ is monic (lead coef $= 1)$, see [unit normalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3008842/242). This is a dupe so you can safely delete the question if the answer is now clear.

Comment: More generally $\, p\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\, \gcd(p,a)\mid p\,$ *properly* (else $\,p\mid \gcd(p,a)\mid a).\,$ OP is special case $\,p\,$ is irred, so its only proper divisors are units (invertibles).

Comment: You can also use: in a PID: $\, (p)\,$ is maximal $\iff p\,$ is irred (by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39649/242)), but this is less general than the above gcd-based proof, which works in any gcd-domain (actually the proof needs only that $\gcd(p,a)\,$ exists)